# ¿Cómo corregir este error con el método POST de la API FETCH?

Tags: php, javascript, fetch

estoy intentando enviar datos por FETCH con el método POST a un archivo php y no me funciona, en el mismo código realizo una petición con el método GET y si me trae los datos que requiero, comparto los códigos a continuación

```
const sendEmail = function(correo){
    fetch('php/Actioner.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({corre: correo})
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)});
 }
```

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $correo = $_POST['corre'];
    echo json_encode('RESPUESTA');   
?>
```

Como pueden ver es algo super simple, solo una prueba, pero por alguna razon me devuelve el siguiente error en consola

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Aclaro que cuando quito la linea  `$correo = $_POST['corre'];`, ahí si me devuelve el echo de la respuesta pero yo requiero enviar datos a ese archivo capturarlos y procesarlos, agradezco cualquier apunte.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes usar es un FormData, este te crea una estructura como si fuera un form html, lo podrias implementar de la siguiente manera:

```
const sendEmail = function(correo){
    const dato = new FormData();
    dato.append('correo', correo);
    fetch('php/Actioner.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: dato,
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)});
 }
```